# ITextSharp and nested form fields

Tags: nested, itext

I need some help to fill a pdf, given by a customer with ITextSharp.

I have a problem with a field that is similar to a radio button.

If I try to list all the fields of my form I can't easily find which field I have to fill and the allowed values.
I've tried to inspect the form with iTextRUPS:

[image]

Can someone help me to find a way to fill these kind of fields ?
Thanks in advance for your help.
Best regards
Fabrizio

Comment: 2.1 is a check box field. One of the possible values is `2.1`. Why don't you ask iText to list the fields like this: [How to get specific types from AcroFields?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-get-specific-types-acrofields-pushbuttonfield-radiocheckfield-etc). This way, you'll discover that 2.1 is a radio field and you can ask that radio field for its possible appearance states (the `unnamed` widget annotations in your RUPS view).

Comment: Thanks Bruno,very useful, now I've another problem, looking at possible states for field 2.1 the values are "2.1" , "Off", "2.2" and others, now I've tried to set one of these values with the following code PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));  AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields; fields.SetField("2.1", "2.1");pdfStamper.Close(); But trying to open the output file the file seems to be corrupted. If I change the SetField line with fields.SetField("2.1", "2.2"); the form is displayed but is no more editable. Can you help me ?

Comment: No, I can't reproduce that problem. When I can't reproduce a problem, there is no problem. I can't fix a problem that doesn't exist as far as I am concerned. What do you mean by corrupted? Are you talking about Reader enabling that gets lost?

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruno, I've double checked the code and all works well (I've made a mistake using a corrupted file before). Thank you for your precious help.